# How to set after callback for specific transition only in aasm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

I have 2 events:

```
event :event1, after: :event2! do
  transitions to: :state2, from: :state1, guard: proc {some func}
  transitions to: :state3, from: :state1
end    

event :event2 do
  transitions to: :state3, from: state2, guard: proc {some func}
end
```

How can I set after callback for first transition only in event1? (I cann't replace second transition to other event)

I tried

```
event :event1 do
  transitions to: :state2, from: :state1, after: :event2!, guard: proc {some func}
  transitions to: :state3, from: :state1
end
```

But it not working

Comment: I didn't get you exactly. You need to do something after the first transition. Can you please explain it more?

Comment: I want run event2 automaticly after event1 without changing the code all over the application. But only for 1 transition, not for all

Comment: If you run another event just after some event then what is the use of the first event why not directly jump to the second event?

Comment: event2 will run or not depending on guard

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I got you exactly.You want run `event2` only after this transition: `transitions to: :state2, from: :state1, guard: proc {some func}`,right?

```
event :event1 do
  transitions to: :state2, from: :state1, :after => Proc.new {|*args| set_process(*args) } , guard: proc {some func}
  transitions to: :state3, from: :state1
end 

def set_process(name)
  event2!
end
```

Or try this.

```
event :event1 do
  transitions to: :state2, from: :state1, guard: proc {some func}
  transitions to: :state3, from: :state1
  after do
    event2! if self.state2?
  end
end    

event :event2 do
  transitions to: :state3, from: state2, guard: proc {some func}
end
```

This code means that, when guard returns true,it will do first transition,else it will do second one.After transition,if it's state2, it will do event2.You can find more detail at [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm).

> In the event of having multiple transitions for an event, the first
>   transition that successfully completes will stop other transitions in
>   the same event from being processed.

You can write any code in the callback,just like rails callbacks.